# Numbers removes Byte-Order-Mask (BOM) from UTF-8 files when exported as CSV. How to fix?

Tags: numbers, java, encoding

I am dealing with a requirement where `CSV` should be `UTF-8` encoded, in order to detect this in my java application I am relying on [Byte Order Masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which is working perfectly fine but we found out that when we export the CSV file via [Numbers](https://www.apple.com/in/numbers/) it removes the BOM.

Can someone help me out with how I can avoid this?

I found a similar question but for Text Edit [TextEdit removes Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) from Unicode/UTF files. How to fix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/textedit-removes-byte-order-mark-bom-from-unicode-utf-files-how-to-fix)

Comment: It is byte order Mark not mask. And it is valid and I think normal for or not to be there for utf-8. If tge Mark us not there what encoding do you assume the file to be?